# Access entire set_value array?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Using codeigniter you retrieve a single value from the form validation by using `set_value('example')`, but can you access the entire array somehow and use it in a foreach such as this below?

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('address', 'Street Address', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('city', 'City', 'required');

if($this->form_validation->run()){
     $entered_values = set_value()
     foreach($entered_values as $value){
     }      
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think outside CI and use php:

```
$entered_values = $_POST
```

Or if you want to use the CI input class:

```
$entered_values = $this->input->post();
```